# Anchor tag in JSP Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Inside WEB-INF folder I have another folder named as views which is having index.jsp with this code `

```
<a href="<c:url value="WebContent/WEB-INF/security/login.jsp" />">click` me</a>
```

and there is one more folder security inside WEB-INF which is having login.jsp.

I want to use a hyperlink just to navigate from index to login page without controller but its throwing a 404 error with description that requested resource is not available..
Below is my dispatcher-servlet

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.sharique.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="ViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView</value>
        </property>
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
```

and this is my web.xml

```
  <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>
  <!--   <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>basicTemplate.xhtml</welcome-file>
     <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
     <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
     <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
     <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
     <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list> -->
   <servlet>
     <servlet-name>MVC-Dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>MVC-Dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: You cannot access resources inside the WEB-INF from a browser.

Comment: controllers are working fine... as you can see for the view resolvers I have given the path... I just want for hyperlink without controllers

Comment: I'm going to repeat, you cannot access resources inside the WEB-INF from a browser. The key is browser, you can access them from the server... Your page will just never work you have to use a controller (you can simply configure a mapping for a url to a view using a `<mvc:view-controller />`. You cannot and never will be able to access a page inside the WEB-INF directly from the browser.

Comment: Clients (e.g., browsers) cannot directly access content under `WEB-INF`. When you render a JSP from a controller the client is not directly accessing the JSP.